# How to run powershell cmdlet in cleared screen and restore original upon finish

Tags: powershell

I am wondering if there is a way, to **Stack** Powershell's **Output Host Temporarily** inside a scope.

For example, scenario is to

- **clear** the screen when the below function runs
- **restore** the original screen when function exits

Demo code:

```
function Print-InBlank
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    #Do something like Clear-Host here
    Write-Host "When you see this everything else is gone"
    Write-Host "Type Ctrl-C to restore"
    #Do something like Restore-Host here
}
```

Comment: would it be enuf to just open another console? if not, perhaps you could add to your Question the rationale for what you are trying to do ... i can't think of any reason for it, but knowing such may point folks to a solution to your actual problem.

Comment: Hello, no its not enough to open to another console. Rational is to do something similar to what vi does. Clear the screen to show something and then return to previous state upon exit

Comment: i cannot think of any way to do what you want ... other than to save the info you _may_ want into a $Var when it is generated. take a look at `Get-Help Tee-Object` for one way to get the info as it is generated.

Comment: "Rational is to do something similar to what vi does." - but why? PowerShell isn't vi. if you make a PowerShell tool, you'll make adoption of it harder if you make it into something that's non-standard compared to most typical functions / cmdlets.

Comment: I dont understand why we discuss about the specs and not about proposals or solutions

Comment: There is no native PowerShell functionality for this. vi and other Unix console apps achieve this using [virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#alternate-screen-buffer) that are available in newer versions of Windows. `Write-Host ([char]27 + "[?1049h"); Read-Host "Hello from alternate buffer! Press enter to return"; Write-Host ([char]27 + "[?1049l");`

Comment: PowerShell 7+ has the `\`e` escape sequence for `ESC` as well, so this can be shortened to ``"`e[?1049h"`` (in those versions).

Comment: @JeroenMostert This was exactly was i was looking for. Thank you! If you want, type it as an answer to accept it